# how to get recently affected rows attribute in model of codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

primary key of `title` table is `id` and it is an auto-increment when I insert data to the table I need to return the `id` of currently inserted row.

my model function is,

```
    function addDate($x, $y, $z) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO title (title,no,user) VALUES ('$x','$y','$z')";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql );
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return "ok";
        } else {
            return "err";
        }
    }
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: I looked at the user guide and the first function is $this->db->insert_id(); Please try to Google first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > **You are wrong. In your function you are getting these three parameters `($x, $y, $z)` But in code you are Inserting `('$t','$n','$a')`**([Question is edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34611072/1))

---

Use `$this->db->insert_id()` to get last insert id

Try this

```
function addDate($x, $y, $z) {

    $data = array(
       'title'  => $x ,
       'no'     => $y ,
       'user'   => $z
    );

    if(!$this->db->insert('title', $data)){
        return FALSE ;
    }
    else{
        $lastId =  $this->db->insert_id(); # add this
        return $lastId; 
    }
}
```

> > **FYI: Don't use `$x`, `$y`, `$z`. use meaningful names like `$title`, `$no`, `$user`**

[Codeigniter Active Record Class Version 2.2.0](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: in case if i want to insert recently affected row's primary key (`title_id`) to another table what would be the modification that i need to make?

Comment: First check this is working or not. If its works accept and come upwith your new question. solved one by one

Comment: if i want to return `title_id` of recently added row 
$lastId =  $this->db->insert_title_id(); 
does it work?

Comment: is title id is autoincrement field??

Comment: so in that id you write select query `where id = $lastId`